# Reading and writing Graph Modeling Language (GML) files

Tags: java, scala, graph

Is there any java API available for reading and writing [Graph Modeling Language (GML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_Modelling_Language) files.

---

In fact, I am looking for any popular graph file format --that is supported by some handy graph editor and visualizer (with good layout management) tools-- and a convenient java API that is provided to reading and writing graphs in this popular format.

My intention is to generate graphs in my application, save it in this standard format, then feed it to the graph editor I mentioned above in order to further manipulate it, and save it again in the same format (that would be naturally readable again in my application).

Among the graph editors, I found [yEd](http://www.yworks.com/en/products/yfiles/yed/) a handy one which supports GML ([Graph Modeling Language](http://www.fim.uni-passau.de/index.php?id=17297&L=1)) format as well. In the GML website, it seems there exist a C language API. So I am looking to see if there is any API in java (scala) that I can read and write this format conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

Try graphstream. API can be found at: http://graphstream-project.org/api/gs-core/